# How to ensure complete file integrity of key files?

Tags: filesystems, file-management, cloud, cloud-storage, data-integrity

A question in regards to file integrity:

How can I ensure that the integrity of a file will always stay 100%?

Important for example when storing key files in regards to encryption etc. on local drive and in cloud. Since the file is key to decrypting various drives, it can not be changed in anyway. 
Self-healing files exist?

Comment: What operating system and filesystem do you use?

Answer (score 0):

> Self-healing files exist?

The best you can hope for (at least in most instances) is to restore from an uncorrupted source once corruption is detected.

Some RAID systems and/or particular file systems can be "self-healing" but these systems typically rely on backups/snapshots as well.

> How can I ensure that the integrity of a file will always stay 100%?

1. Create checksums for healthy files and use those checksums to verify later copies.
2. Have multiple backups, preferably 3+ copies total (i.e. the original and two spares).
3. Check all of these in a somewhat regular manner to ensure integrity.

These general rules often apply to "self-healing" systems as well as "normal" backups. However, with "self-healing" systems, they are typically applied behind the scenes so that it isn't always immediately obvious this is what is happening.

---

*When doing manual backups, especially with relatively large amounts of data, you will likely want to store it in a manner that promotes easy restoration. This probably includes minimal duplication of non-essential files, clear versioning of some sort (by date or other methods) and a solid organization scheme you can adhere to over the course of many backups.*

---